# Trying to create a picture with PSTtricks

Tags: pstricks, gradient, pst-3dplot

I'm trying to create a picture of a paraboloid, as shown in the figure, with the package `pstricks` but I'm getting some errors while writing the parameters for the parabola and the ellipse (`gradangle,gradbegin,gradend`,...). Any suggestions?
[image]

Here's my code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-3)(6,10)
\parabola[gradangle=90,fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=white,gradend=darkgray,gradmidpoint=1](-3,7)(0,1)
\psellipse[gradangle=90,fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=white,gradend=darkgray,gradmidpoint=0.2](0,7)(3,0.5)
\psline{->}(-4,0)(6,0)
\psline{->}(4,4)(-3,-3)
\psline{->}(0,6.5)(0,10)
\psline(0,-3)(0,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `pst-grad` after `pstricks` coding shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-grad}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-3)(6,10)
\parabola[gradangle=90,fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=white,gradend=darkgray,gradmidpoint=1](-3,7)(0,1)
\psellipse[gradangle=90,fillstyle=gradient,gradbegin=white,gradend=darkgray,gradmidpoint=0.2](0,7)(3,0.5)
\psline{->}(-4,0)(6,0)
\psline{->}(4,4)(-3,-3)
\psline{->}(0,6.5)(0,10)
\psline(0,-3)(0,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you add an image to your answer? That would be helpful/nice.